# Defaultdict with list as a value to Dataframe to CSV

Tags: python, pandas

I have a defaultdict with values of different data types

`defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'id': ['042'], 'success': [1, 1, 1]})`

and want to save it to a file with pandas.

The mwe code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import collections
dd = collections.defaultdict(list)
dd['id'].append('42')
for x in range(3):
    dd['success'].append(1)
print(dd)
pd.DataFrame(dd).to_csv('test.csv')
```

I get a `ValueError: arrays must all be same length`. How can I write the list `'success'` into one csv cell?

Comment: Using a DataFrame only as a bridge to output a csv file looks like a huge overkill. Why not to use the straightforward `csv.writer`?

Comment: What data do you expect that `DataFrame` to produce if it could?

Comment: @DeepSpace You are totally right. However, the above example is only a minimal example from a much larger script, where I do much more stuff.

Comment: @JonClements IDs will be always numbers, Success will always be a list of 3 elements, each one either 1 or 0 in my main script. Here I simplified this to 1 only.

Comment: @absurd wouldn't your starting structure then be better off as the *key* of your (default)dictionary being `id` and it's *values* `[1, 1, 1]` or whatever... so it'd be `{'042': [1, 1, 1], '123': [0, 1, 1]}` instead of a dictionary of two fields of id and success?

Comment: @JonClements In my case that would not be an alternative as I need the output in rows/long format as further scripts depend on it.

Comment: @absurd so how would your defaultdict look with multiple "ids" and "success" fields?

Comment: @JonClements Ahh. Thank you. Now I see the problem properly. It would be e.g. ```{'id': ['042', '043'], 'success': [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]}```. But it should be ```{'id': ['042', '043'], 'success': [[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1]]}```

Comment: @absurd yes... sounds like you've solved it... :) But then you might well be better of using the `id` as the key and `success` as the values - that way you can directly lookup based on id using just the dict and still get a list of keys or a list of values from the dictionary after... depends what you're doing though.

Comment: @JonClements Yes, that is right. However, one possible post hoc query might be: look up all ids where there is at least one 0 in success...

Comment: @absurd but that's just: `{k for k, v in your_dict.items() if 0 in v}`or using the dataframe if you wanted... that doesn't strike me as a great example to justify the nesting you're doing... (it's also a lot less work than the method you seem to be aiming for)

Comment: @JonClements ...yes, if I could remain in the python world for this (and not on the sql side...)

Comment: Okay... you mention CSV, now you mention SQL... I'm completely baffled... maybe it's worth asking a question that's really what you're after as I've got a horrible feeling of Alice going down the rabbit hole here :) (you don't really need pandas to create a CSV file, but you can use pandas to interface with DBs if you wanted... if you skip pandas because you're just creating a CSV file, then that's not going to be the best `dict` structure to write it with etc...)...

Comment: @JonClements I am sorry. I just wanted to be as brief as possible to stick to the very problem -- which I found with your help. Thank you. The whole thing is a larger workflow with python, postgres etc. which I have not created by my own, I am just working to get some input created by python into csv, which is then fetched by some existing sql routines. Therefore I am somewhat restricted on how to design the csv output. However, I think my question is solved at this point.

Comment: @absurd okay - feel free to make a self-answer for the record... :)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

Use `pandas.Series` to force a single dimensional perspective

```
d = defaultdict(list)
d['id'] = ['042']
d['success'] = [1, 1, 1]

pd.Series(d)

id             [042]
success    [1, 1, 1]
dtype: object
```